# How to get datastore name/id column value

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to get name/id column value for a datastore kind entity using next(iter(result)) below but looking for other ways to do it. I tried this way result[0]['id'] but it did not work . Any suggestions?

```
    query = self.ds.query(kind=self.__tablename__)
    query.add_filter('email', '=', self.email)
    result = query.fetch(1)
    id = next(iter(result))
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `next(iter(result))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key for a Datastore Entity is special property that isn't part of the properties dictionary.

As documented at https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/datastore/entities.html, you can get the id by calling `id` on the entity itself.  So `list(result)[0].id` or `list(result)[0].key.id` .