# How do I go about setting up my scalars and revolvers to retrieve the key/id from Cloud Datastore?

Tags: flask, graphql, google-cloud-datastore, graphene-python

I'm using the graphene-python library and google cloud datastore as my database. I can query and get back the correct information on all columns except for the Name/ID column.How do I get information from that column?

TIA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get datastore name/id column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52669880/how-to-get-datastore-name-id-column-value)

Answer (score 0):

From [How to get datastore name/id column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52669880/how-to-get-datastore-name-id-column-value/52730948#52730948) :

The key for a Datastore Entity is special property that isn't part of the properties dictionary.

As documented at https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/datastore/entities.html, you can get the id by calling id on the entity itself. So list(result)[0].id or list(result)[0].key.id .