# GCP: Fetch the primary key field along with other fields in Datastore

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I would like to fetch all the column from the datatstore kind.

[datastore fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTBiu.png)

```
#To get all books(all entity) from the datastore
@app.route("/getbookdetails", methods=['GET'])
  def getbookdetails():
  query=client.query(kind='tableofbooks')
  results = list(query.fetch())
  return json.dumps(results)
```

currently getting the below response as output but I would like to fetch the id which is also present in the datastore as the primary key

```
[
    {
        "author": "new author",
        "description": "Google Datastore",
        "title": "sample insert",
        "yearofpublication": 2021
    }]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get datastore name/id column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52669880/how-to-get-datastore-name-id-column-value)

Comment: This is the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69000107/how-do-i-go-about-setting-up-my-scalars-and-revolvers-to-retrieve-the-key-id-fro/69004385 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52669880/how-to-get-datastore-name-id-column-value .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue with the code below.

```
query=client.query(kind='tableofbooks')
        mylist=query.fetch()
        bookarray=[]
        for x in mylist:
            thisdict ={
                 "id":x.id,
                 "author":x['author'],
                 "description":x['description'],
                 "title":x['title'],
                 "yearofpublication":x['yearofpublication'],
            }
            bookarray.append(thisdict)
        return json.dumps(bookarray)
```